# How can I design two tables which are mutually dependent on one another? That is, TableA's rows cannot exist without a row in TableB, and vice versa

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's suppose we have the following requirements from the application perspective:

[image: Application requirements]

SuperClass has a few attributes like Type, PropertyA, PropertyB, etc.
SubClassA, SubClassB, SubClassC all inherit these attributes, and of course can have their own individual attributes.
Note that there are around 20 sub-classes. I just listed out three for the sake of the example.

The main thing to keep in mind is that an instance of SuperClass must be one and only one SubClass. So a SuperClass instance cannot be both SubClassA and SubClassB, and a SuperClass instance cannot exist on its own.
Additionally, instances of the same Type attribute can exist in multiple SubClasses. For example, `Type == 'Type1'` can be get multiple rows from SubClassA and SubClassC.

Based on this, I would normally not even create the SuperClass table. And instead just have the various SubClass tables like so:
[image: Tables]
I'd just repeat the inherited attributes in each of the tables. Problem solved.

However, the only reason I'm considering created a SuperClass table is because I would like to run a query which would allow me to get all instances of a particular type. Like so:

> SELECT PropertyA FROM SuperClass WHERE Type = 'Type1';

This could potentially get me rows from multiple sub-classes. This would avoid me the pain of going through all the sub-class tables.

So, in essence, a row cannot exist in SuperClass table without a corresponding row in a sub-class table. On top of that, a row cannot exist in a sub-class table without a corresponding row in SuperClass table.

Obviously, this is pretty much impossible since we then won't be able to insert or delete any rows.

I have been trying to figure out a solution for a couple of days now. And since I'm unable to, I'm hoping someone from here can lead me towards the right path.

I just need to be able to get the sub-classes of the same Type from one query.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you looked at [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html)? Sounds like it would do what you want, though it does come with a few [limitations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#ddl-inherit-caveats).

Answer (score 1):

You can make this easily using a deferred constraint
Example:

```
 create table test
 (id serial primary key,
  child_id integer);

 create table test2
(id serial primary key,
 child_id integer references test(id) deferrable initially deferred);

 alter table test2 add constraint my_own_grandpa 
 foreign key (child_id) references test2(id) deferrable initially deferred;
```